# v-for set current border color after click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue components who loads a list of users:

```
        <div
        v-for="(user, index) in users"
        class="user rounded-md border px-5 py-3 mr-5"
        :class="{ 'border-gray-400':!isp && !isa && !isi, 'border-green-400': isp, 'border-red-400': isa, 'border-yellow-400': && isi }"
    >
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="mt-1 font-medium">
                {{ user.fullname }}
            </div>
            <div class="flex ml-3">
                <div class="cursor-pointer" @click="isPresent(student.id)">
                    Available
                </div>
                <div class="ml-3 cursor-pointer" @click="isAbsent(student.id)">
                    Not available
                </div>
                <div class="ml-3 cursor-pointer" @click="addNotes(student.id)">
                    Add Notes
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The users are loaded by ajax with the created() function:

```
    created() {
            axios
                .get("/api/users)
                .then(resp => {
                        this.users = resp.data.users;
                    }
                )
                .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));

    },
```

Now when i click on "`Available`", an ajax request is send to the server and the border of the current user should be `green`, because the current users `isp` ( is present ) variable should be set to `true`.

If the second user - for example - is "`Not Available`", this users `isa` ( is absent ) variable should be set to `true` and the border will become `red`.

The ajax request for setting the attendance looks like this:

```
            axios
                    .post('/api/store', data)
                    .then(resp => {
                            if (resp.status == 200) {
                                 switch (state) {
                                       case 'present':
                                       this.isp = true;
                                       break;
                                 case 'absent':
                                       this.isa = true;
                                       break;
                                 case 'late':
                                       this.isi = true;
                                       break;
                                 case 'ill':
                                       this.isi = true;
                                       break;

                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err.response);

                    });
```

When the border of the second user is red, the first one should stay green.

Actually all the borders are set to green, red or yellow no matter which user i click.
I have also tried with the index - the right user was marked, but all the other users status were removed.

Comment: you should have an array on data which defines the state per user. so you end up with something like: `this.users[index].isp = true`

Comment: That's a great idea @oshell - thank you! I tried another way and it didn't work - your approach is much better! Thanks ;-)

Comment: just be aware that nested values are not always reactive, especially when you add them later. you should use this.$set in these cases.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - that is exactly what i needed! You saved my day ;-)